# Update entire colum in datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am using jquery datatable plugin and I want to update entire column values on click of button. How do i do that.

I tried using fnUpdate but here we need to specify row and column.

This my html code for table

```
<table id="regions" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Region</th>  
          <th>Min Score</th>  // Want min max col editable
          <th>Max Score</th> //min < max                          
      </tr>                         
  </thead>

  <tbody>   
    <% for scores_row in scores_regions %>                                                   
    <tr>
            <td><%= label_tag 'regions[]',scores_row.at(0) %></td>  
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1000</td>
   </tr>

   <% end %>
  </tbody>      
</table>
```

This is my jquery code ,which applies to second row third column..I want all rows third column..

```
$('#button_max_apply').click(function(){ 
    oTable.fnUpdate("text to apply",1,2);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. There is [jQuery DataTables Data Manager](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/) that can make table enhanced by DataTables plug-in editable. There is also [DataTables Editor](https://editor.datatables.net) but it's not free.

Comment: I modified as per your suggestion.Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use `fnUpdate()` in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
myTable.column(2).nodes().each(function(node, index, dt){
  myTable.cell(node).data('40');
});
```

- myTable.column(2).nodes() will get the list of nodes of a particular column.
- myTable.cell(node) will get a particular cell provided node is the DOM element.

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/10/**

Comment: The problem with this method is that with a huge table the loop takes more than 1 minute to change all values